# Simulate competing risks

Tags: survival, simulation, statistical-power, competing-risks

I am trying to simulate competing risks data for a power analysis. Based on historical data, we know that after 12 months:

- 40% had experienced the event of interest
- 20% had experienced the competing event
- 40% had not experienced either of the events after 12 months.

I have figured out that I can simulate the distribution of patients who experience an event - ignoring the censored patients - by setting the rate parameter of the exponential distribution for the event to interest $\lambda_E = \log(\frac{1}{1-0.4})/12$ and the rate parameter for the competing event $\lambda_{CE}=\frac{0.2}{0.4}\lambda_E$. This yields two time-to-event distributions with the desired proportion of $2/3$ with the event of interest and $1/3$ with the competing event.

However, if I add the censoring after 12 months, the proportions are not any more as desired. I suspect I will need to figure out the distribution of the combined risks, and for the cause-specific time-to-events some more general distribution, such as Weibull distribution, might be required, but I don't know where to start.

---

Some simulation code:

```
library(tidyverse)
N=1e5
rate_event_of_interest <- log(1/(1-0.44))/12
time_to_event_of_interest <- rexp(n=N, rate=rate_event_of_interest)
time_to_competing_event <- rexp(n=N, rate=rate_event_of_interest*(0.2/0.44)) 

comprsk_data <- tibble("time_to_event_of_interest"=time_to_event_of_interest, "time_to_competing_event"=time_to_competing_event) %>% 
  mutate(time_to_event = case_when(time_to_competing_event<time_to_event_of_interest ~ time_to_competing_event,
                                   time_to_competing_event>time_to_event_of_interest ~ time_to_event_of_interest),
         event = case_when(time_to_competing_event<time_to_event_of_interest & time_to_event<12 ~ "competing event",
                           time_to_competing_event>time_to_event_of_interest & time_to_event<12 ~ "event of interest",
                           time_to_event>=12 ~ "censored")) 
table(comprsk_data$event)
>  censored   competing event event of interest 
>    43099             17961             38940 
# this should 40000, 20000 and 40000
```